# Accessing Facebook birthday, hometown and other data with passportJS in Node

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to add OAuth2 logins to my app that is built on Node/ExpressJS/MongoDB/PassportJS.

I can successfully log in using this method, but I cannot get certain bits of information. The only things I've  been able to access are `email`, `name` and `fbId` fields - I cannot currently access birthdays, likes, hometowns and other info from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

My userSchema is set up like this:

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fbId: String,
    name: String,
    email: { type:String, lowercase: true },
    gender: String,
    birthday: String,
    hometown: Object,
    location: Object,
    likes: Array
});
```

This is the code running on my Express server:

```js
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.development.fb.appId,
    clientSecret: config.development.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.development.fb.url + 'fbauthed'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      var query = User.findOne({ 'fbId': profile.id });
      query.exec(function(err, oldUser) {
        if (oldUser) {
          console.log('Existing user: ' + oldUser.name + ' found and logged in!');
          done(null, oldUser);
        } else {
          var newUser = new User();
          newUser.fbId = profile.id;
          newUser.name = profile.displayName;
          newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
          newUser.gender = profile.gender;
          newUser.birthday = profile.birthday;
          newUser.hometown = profile.hometown;
          newUser.location = profile.location;
          newUser.likes = profile.likes;

          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            console.log('New user: ' + newUser.name + ' created and logged in!');
            done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
));
app.get('/fbauth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ failureRedirect: '/' }), function(req, res){}
```

When I try to log in and try to access these properties, I get:

```js
fbId: String, // Defined
name: String, // Defined
email: { type:String, lowercase: true }, // Defined
gender: String, // Defined
birthday: String, // UNDEFINED
hometown: Object, // UNDEFINED
location: Object, // UNDEFINED
likes: Array // UNDEFINED
```

Am I trying to access them incorrectly? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It was in my original call to facebook, here:

```
app.get('/fbauth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
```

The `scope` section is the things that you're getting authentication from the user for. If you look [at the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) you'll see that "birthday" requires `user_birthday` and "likes" requires `user_likes`. So here's what I had to do:

```
app.get('/fbauth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_likes'] }));
```

I then unauthenticated the app from my facebook account, deleted my user profile from my database, logged out and restarted the authentication, and it worked just fine. The above suggestion of doing a `console.log(profile)` was good as it helps you see what data Facebook is actually sending back.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Profile holds a lot of data which can be accessed. In particular hometown can be accessed by

```
newuser.hometown= profile._json.hometown.name;
```

I suggest to understand the structure of

```
profile
```

you add

```
console.log(profile);
```

in

```
process.nextTick(function() {
 console.log(profile);
}
```

before you give the commands for newuser.xxx = profile.xxx;    This will print the structure of profile on your console which you can then read to understand how to access relevant fields.